# How do I make updates to data in a unique-constrained column across multiple rows without risking violating the constraint?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, wpf, vb.net

I have a table with a column with a unique constraint. The user will edit the data in this table in the form of a DataTable bound to a DataGrid. Once they are done modifying the data, the save function must apply their changes back to the database. For application architecture reasons, each change to the database must be performed as a create, update, or delete action one row at a time. I can validate the DataTable to be sure that the end result does not violate the constraint, but it seems impossible to verify that it will never be violated in between. Even if I do not allow duplicate values inside the DataGrid itself, the user could put a placeholder value in while making the modifications that would violate the constraint, and the DataTable class only seems to store the original and final versions of each row, not the intermediate versions.

How can I avoid any unique constraint violations while making these changes to the data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to update all of the constrained values in a SQL statement:

```
UPDATE [Foo] Set [SomeUniqueValue] = CASE [ID] WHEN 1 THEN 'A' WHEN 2 THEN 'B' WHEN 3 THEN 'C' END WHERE [ID] IN (1,2,3)
```

This will not violate the unique if you were swapping the values around, as long as the uniqueness is preserved by the time the statement is finished.

If you must do it one row at a time, you would likely have to brute force run through your list of updates, catching errors when it failed, and in a loop keep retrying the ones that errored, until all updates were completed, or no more updates could be made:

```
bool didSomething;
List<Row> rowsThatNeedToTryAgain = new List<Row>();
do {
   didSomething = false;
   rowsThatNeedToTryAgain.Clear();
   foreach (Row row in rowsToUpdate) {
      try {
         UpdateTheRowInTheDatabase(row);
         didSomething = true;
      } catch {
         rowsThatNeedToTryAgain.Add(row);
      }
   }
   rowsToUpdate.Clear();
   rowsToUpdate.AddRange(rowsThatNeedToTryAgain);
} while (didSomething && rowsThatNeedToTryAgain.Count > 0);

if (rowsThatNeedToTryAgain.Count > 0) 
   throw new Exception("sorry, couldn't do 'em all");
```

A more elegant solution might do this from code without hitting the database, but that would assume your process is the only one updates at that time.